# GWT + Spring Security login issue after logout

Tags: spring, gwt, authentication, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security to secure access to my GWT's first page application **"/HumanResources.html"**. It checks if the credentials of the user are correct (by comparing them with ldap content) and look if the user exists in database (custom authorized table).

First time user login, there is no trouble, then the user logout and a ".jsp" page is displayed.
But when he wants to access again to "HumanResources.html" page, the authentication is apparently ignored (login form isn't displayed) and the page is displayed. Only the interface is visible, data is retrieved by secured RPC services.

This problem appears on external Tomcat Server (tested on Firefox and Chrome), but not on GWT Dev mode. CTRL + F5 seems to work, and I looked for other cache issues but it didn't help.

Can anyone help me ?

A part of my **security-applicationContext.xml** :

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false">
    <intercept-url pattern="/HumanResources.html" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login 
        login-page='/login.jsp'
        authentication-failure-url = "/login.jsp?login_error=1"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="HRAuthenticationHandler" />
    <logout 
        logout-url="/logout" 
        logout-success-url="/logout.jsp" 
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="HRAuthenticationHandler" class="lu.sfeir.candidate.server.auth.HRAuthenticationHandler">
    <beans:property name="useReferer" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<ldap-server url="${ldap.serverUrl}" manager-dn="${ldap.adminLogin}" manager-password="${ldap.adminPassword}" />

<authentication-manager>
    <ldap-authentication-provider 
        group-search-base="${ldap.groups}"
        user-search-base="${ldap.users}"
        user-search-filter="${ldap.userId}">
    </ldap-authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

and my custom **AuthenticationHandler implementation** :

```
public class HRAuthenticationHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorizedUsersDao usersDao;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException,
            ServletException {

        // Check if the user exist in the DB
        if(usersDao.findUser(((UserDetails)authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername())) {
            // Redirect to home page
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        } else {
            // Redirect to error page
            response.sendRedirect("/spring_security_login?login_error");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: 
Sorry for missleading You.
I dig a bit and found that security doesnt work cause user browser is caching xxx.html page, js,css etc
You can: 
1) force refresh page by setting html headders : 
Thats the simplest solution, and since You are using secure RPC services that should be enaught for You.
Or disable caching at all.

Mind it will increase Your network traffic.

2) 
our application is checking if security error ocured in RPC:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.InvocationException;

public abstract class CustomAsyncCallback<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        if (caught instanceof InvocationException) {
            InvocationException ie = (InvocationException) caught;
            if(ie.getMessage().contains("j_spring_security_check")) {
                Window.alert("User session expired, please login again");
                Window.open(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "login.jsp", "_self", null);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You must call it somewhere ie while displaying You current logged user:

```
    userSecurityService.getUser(new CustomAsyncCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            usrLoginLbl.setText(result);
        }
    });
```

or You may catch this exception to one of yours onFailure method

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried your solution by adding an access role (ROLE_HR) to HumanResources.html but it didn't work :/ When I re-log, the authentication phase is "skiped"...

Comment: Thanks again !
Html headers could be the best solution (few users are connected to the application). I've always looked at this solution but it didn't worked last time I tried (maybe I'm doing it wrong). Could you show me how to deal with it ?

Comment: we do it 2) way-the code is in my post. In RPC in onFailure we handle security exceptions

Comment: Okay ! The problem is : I can't do this because I'm not implementing a generic custom RPC, and editing all my onFailure RPC calls could take a very long time :/